# "MIPS" Runtime exception at 0x0040003c: fetch address not aligned on word boundary 0x10010005 error

Tags: assembly, mips

```
 the C++ version is

 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int x[10] = {0};
 int pos[6] = {1, 3, 6, 9, -1, -1};
 int data[6] = {73, 47, 23, 26, -1, -1};
 int main() {

 for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
  if (pos[i] >= 0) {
    int temp = pos[i];
    x[temp] = data[i];
  }
}

  for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
  cout << x[i] << endl;
}
```

}

```
     .data
 x: .word   0:10
 pos:   .word   1
    .word   3
    .word   6
    .word   9
    .word   -1
    .word   -1
data:   .word   73
    .word   47
    .word   23
    .word   26
    .word   -1
    .word   -1

endl:   .asciiz "\n"

# i     $s0
# &x[0]     $s1
# &pos[0]   $s2
# &data[0]  $s3
# 6, 10     $s6

    .text
main:   la  $s1, x
    la  $s2, pos
    la  $s3, data
    li  $s6, 6
    li      $s0, 0          #  for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
for:    mul $t0,$s0,4       #    if (pos[i] >= 0) {
    add     $t0,$s2,$s0
    lw  $t1,($t0)
    blt     $t1,0,loop


    add  $t2, $s1,$t1    # int temp = pos[i]        
    lw   $t3,4($t2)             #      x[temp] = data[i];   
    add  $t4, $s3,$s0
    lw   $t5, 4($t4)
    sw   $t3, ($t5)

loop:  addi $s0, $s0,1          #    }
    blt $s0, $s6, for           #  }
```

I've been trying to figure this out I get "not alignment on word boundary error" and I can't figure out why the error appears to start at lw   $t3,4($t2)after the first iteration the expected output is
 0
73
0
47
0
0
23
0
0
26

Comment: `int temp = pos[i]` what's inside pos?

Comment: int pos[6] = {1, 3, 6, 9, -1, -1};
int data[6] = {73, 47, 23, 26, -1, -1};

Comment: You can also post your code as an edit on your question: makes it better readable XD.  So: which value do you expect when using `x[-1]` or `x[9]`?

Comment: the expected output should be  0,
73,
0,
47,
0,
0,
23,
0,
0,
26,

Comment: Ah, my bad; missed the `>=0` part

Comment: This problem was already asked in a similar question yesterday. See the question and my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713231/what-am-i-doing-wrong-when-converting-these-lines-of-c-into-assembly-mips/39734053#39734053